# get a Subscription on a view

Tags: php, mysql, select, subscription

i want to give a query on a mySQL db with php
before this, i have a "create view" and it works right. after that, i should give a query with 2 select or more and this selects should be Subscript with each other.

i know we can "union" 2 select but i don't now the keyword of Subscription. :((

first Query:

```
    CREATE VIEW `obj` AS
SELECT
    `object`.id,
    `course`.name course,
    `major`.name major,
    `master`.lname master,
    `course`.id id_course,
    `major`.id id_major,
    `master`.id id_master

FROM
    `course`,
    `major`,
    `master`,
    `object`,
    `type`
WHERE 
    object.id_major=major.id and
    object.id_master=master.id and
    object.id_course=course.id and
    object.id_type=type.id";
```

second Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `obj` WHERE $major
???
SELECT * FROM `obj` WHERE $master
```

Comment: Subscription? Are you sure? Is it possible you meant subtraction?

Comment: no, i want to have Common results between them.